# Como ir esvaziando buffer do PHP durante a execução

Tags: php, buffer

Eu já vi em algum lugar um código que configura o PHP pra ir esvaziando o *Buffer* (ir imprimindo na tela) durante a execução do *script* sem a necessidade de esperar toda a execução para que algo seja exibido.

Alguém já viu ou sabe que comando é esse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O método que você procure é o [`ob_flush`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php).

Também é possível, ao invés de ficar liberando o *buffer* de tempos em tempos, de fazer o output do buffer sempre que ocorrer um `echo` com:

```
ob_implicit_flush(true);
```

Finalmente, pode-se configurar diretamente no `php.ini`:

```
implicit_flush = Off
```

Comment: Exatamente, eu já conhecia e uso constantemente o `ob_flush` pra colocar o conteúdo do buffer em variáveis, mas não me liguei que ele também descarregava o buffer na tela... :D Agora esse do `ob_implicit_flush` foi demais, não conhecia, muito bom.

Comment: Você pode configurar a diretiva `implicit_flush` no `php.ini`, e assim não precisa setar isso sempre :)

Comment: Valeu por essa informação, talvez seja útil para pessoas que precisem (adicione a diretiva na respota), mas eu preciso dessa funcionalidade apenas para uma função específica então é melhor apenas chamar a função no arquivo.

Comment: @KaduAmaral Feito. :)